# How can I add a fill color to my font icon in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have custom font icons and one of those is a star. This star icon is required to be filled in some color when clicked.

My font icon is drawn by the `BasicText` composable:

```kotlin
    BasicText(
        text = iconUnicode.codePointToString(),
        modifier = modifier,
        style = iconStyle,
    )
```

The `iconStyle` is a simple `TextStyle` via which I can set the icons tint. But how can I fill the icon?

Answer (score 0):

If iconStyle is a simple TextStyle you can set the TextStyle font color by calling

> .copy(color = ...)

Something like this:

```
BasicText(
        text = iconUnicode.codePointToString(),
        modifier = modifier,
        style = iconStyle.copy(color = ...),
    )
```

Comment: Thank you. That missed the point as this just tints the icon, what I already do. What I was looking for is a way to fill specific parts of the icon with color. I figured that I need another icon for that.